# JavaScript alert on scrolling

Tags: javascript, html

How can I display an alert using javascript when a user scrolls to a particular portion of a webpage. i tried to display the same by checking `document.body.clientWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth` for a particular value and displaying the alert. But it didn't work. please help me.

Comment: width for scrolling? Strange.

Comment: @Shikiryu not in parallax-style :)

Comment: Agree with Shikiryu !

Comment: it's not for parallax or anything. i just want my horizontal scrollbar to display this

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code :

```
var alertHeight = 500;
var alerted = false;

window.onscroll = function() {
   if (window.scrollHeight >= alertHeight && !alerted) {
      alert('Portion Reached for first time!');
      alerted = true;
   }
}
```

This will alert the user when they scroll beyond the 500px mark, and will only alert them the first time.

Comment: but it didnt work. does this work on document.documentElement or what?

Comment: Not 100% sure, could you supply us some Markup or Code to better explain your specific issue?

Comment: suppose i have clientHeight of document. then after some scrolling, clientHeight will be changed. i want an alert to be displayed at this point.

Comment: Then why not display the alert when you change the clientHeight? or are you wanting to know how to do that?

Comment: i tried displaying the alert at a particular clientHeight of documentElement. but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste in **all** of the javascript code you tried for this? We will then be able to help you correct it.

Comment: I think you might be getting confused with what `clientHeight` is. The clientHeight is not the currently scrolled position. Try looking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.clientHeight for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You should check using `==` operator. Change your code to:

```
document.body.clientWidth == document.documentElement.clientWidth
```

But your code will not set anything, as it is an assignment operator, so it won't work.

Comment: No, I only meant cross-browser clientWidth property here. It should be written my way.